# Docker replicate UID/GID in container from host

Tags: permissions, docker

When creating Docker containers I keep running into the issue of the UID/GID not being reflected in the container (I realize this is by design).  What I am looking for is a way to keep host permissions reasonable and / or to replicate the UID/GID from the host user / group accounts in my Docker container.  For instance:

host -

woot4moo:x:504:504:woot4moo:/home/woot4moo:/bin/bash

I would like this same behavior in the Docker container.  That being said, is this even the right way to do this type of thing?  My belief is I could simply run:

```
useradd -u 504 -g 504 woot4moo
```

as part of my Dockerfile, but I am not sure if that is valid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You wouldn't want to run that as part of the image build process (in your Dockerfile), because the host on which someone is running a container is often *not* the host on which you are building the image.

One way of solving this is passing in UID/GID information via environment variables:

```
docker run -e APP_UID=100 -e APP_GID=100 ...
```

And then have an `ENTRYPOINT` script that includes something like the following before running the `CMD`:

```
useradd -c 'container user' -u $APP_UID -g $APP_GID appuser
chown -R $APP_UID:$APP_GID /app/data
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the group APP_GID does not exist. Could use `groupadd --force --gid ${APP_GID} appuser`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues and typically included entrypoint scripts in every image as it has already been mentioned (using https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec for interactive terminal programs). However, I kept repeating the same steps in multiple Dockerfiles. But after I used "docker.inside" from Jenkins Pipeline which does the user id handling auto-magically, I decided to build a Python 3 package based on docker-py to do this in a (hopefully) similar way (with some extended features I found helpful):

https://github.com/boon-code/docker-inside

I realize that the post is rather old; Maybe it's still helpful to someone with the same problem...

Comment: ~3 years ago it was for a relatively corner use case.  I am not sure if it still makes sense these days