# Single container definition with different users

Tags: docker

Due to reasons, we have two networks. On network A, the USER who should execute the process in the container might be *usera*. On network B, the User might be *userb*. The uid/gid of the users must match ldap definitions, and these are well defined. There are persistent files written by the process to bind mounted directories on the SAN (and clearly a different SAN on each network), so the process owner is important.

If there were only a single USER, I would do the following:

```
FROM <base image>
RUN groupadd -g 999 usera && useradd -u 999 -g 999 usera
USER usera
CMD ["process", "'params"]
```

Then the running process would be owned by usera, and all would be well.

However, it would be nice if it were possible to build a single container, but at the point of container startup have the user be set via some parameter.

I suspect it might be possible by having an `ENTRYPOINT` added to the Dockerfile, and then perhaps sending values via the `docker run -e USER=[usera|userb]`, but I  am just coming up to speed with Docker, so I'm not sure exactly how that would work.

I've looked at [processes in containers should not run as root](https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b), which gave some suggestions. Also, we absolutely cannot have the container run as root. I also looked at [Docker Replicate UID/GID in container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397496/docker-replicate-uid-gid-in-container-from-host), which provided a hint on possibly sending values via `-e`, but the admonishment about the id mismatch on the build system and running system doesn't apply.

How may I achieve this different user owning a process, possibly by passing in a value (though, if I can have a sophisticated enough script, I can detect what network the container is running on, and I could potentially set some variable automatically)?

Edit: due to auditing and review requirements, it would be cleaner if it were possible to ensure the user setting (or fail to start if one were not provided), rather than using, e.g., the `--user` parameter to the `docker run`. Nonetheless, if the only/best approach is the `--user`, then so be it.

Comment: You could check the effective uid on the process startup and abort if is zero (root), to ensure that the process doesn't run as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Run a script as root (this will be the entrypoint), pass the UID/GID as environment variables, use `usermod|groupmod` to change the user/group id then exec the real process using the new user. Check the gogs/gogs image for an [example](https://github.com/gogs/gogs/blob/2a86b3e31d19e8dab987dcf927cfb3363e946d53/docker/start.sh#L41) of a container where the UID/GID can be customized.
- Use the [`--user`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) switch on the docker run command so the process starts with the correct UID/GID. You don't need to create a user on the Dockerfile with this option as the UID will be overriden with the one from the command line.

The problem with the second approach is that you must prepare the filesystem permissions beforehand, as you cannot chown/chmod once the process is started.