# Docker: executing all commands as local user and not root

Tags: docker, dockerfile, file-permissions, user-permissions

How do I run `docker run` and `docker-compose up/run` commands so that the process inside the docker is run by a user with the same `uuid` as my local user?

I need to do this so that any files generated by an "inside-docker" process would have ownership permissions of my local user.

### To replicate:

Use the [alpine:3.9](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine?tab=description) container, mount in a volume for the file to be written and create the file. Assume my current username is `user`.

```
mkdir output_dir #Create an output directory
docker run -it --rm --volume "/path/to/output_dir:/tmp" alpine:3.9 touch /tmp/file.txt
ls -la output_dir/file.txt
```

Will give the output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb  7 19:51 /path/to/output_dir/file.txt
```

This means I need to `sudo chown user:user /path/to/output_dir/file.txt` to have access as my current user on my own file system.

#### How do I do this without this extra step?

### Idea that comes to mind:

Add a Docker [Entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) which will create a user inside the container with the same `uuid` as my local user and execute any code as that user.

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
TEMP_UID="${TEMP_UID:-1000}"
set -ux
useradd -s /bin/false --no-create-home -u ${TEMP_UID} temp
#su-exec is an executable which makes it easy to run a process as a specific user.
exec su-exec temp $@
```

The problem with this is I will have to inject the `TEMP_UID=<user_id>` as an environment variable at every `docker run` command or include in my `docker-compose.yml` file for every `docker-compose up/run` command. If `Docker` has an internal variable that keeps track of the `uuid` of the user that ran it, I would just use that. But I can't seem to find such an internal variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker replicate UID/GID in container from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397496/docker-replicate-uid-gid-in-container-from-host)

Comment: The `fix-perms` script here may interest you: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base

Comment: @BMitch, very interesting! I'll try this out and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is as simple as

```
docker run --user ${UID} -it --rm --volume "/path/to/output_dir:/tmp" alpine:3.9 touch /tmp/file.txt
```

Note I injected `--user ${UID}` into your example command.

Comment: This works, but I'd like to try and avoid having to inject the user every time, as mentioned in my last paragraph

Comment: For me this has the effect that files inside the container are not accessible if the UID is not the typical 1000 that the non-root user inside the container has.

Comment: @JanSchatz I do not understand.  Docker does not have a typical non-root user.  The typical user is root.  Wouldn't UID be the value that your user has?  I do not know for sure because docker has been obviated by nix.

Comment: Of course this applies to the case where you create and set a non-root user. I try to avoid running as root.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the current options require a change outside of the container to pass in the current user, or rely on variables that may not exist in all environments. My preferred solution, since the goal is to fix file permissions on mounted volumes, is to start the entrypoint as root with a script that changes the container userid to match that of the volume mount's userid. And then the end of the entrypoint launches the application with a `exec gosu $app_user_name "$@"` to switch from root to that application user that was modified inside of the container.

Scripts to do this are in my [base image repo](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base). Take note of the `fix-perms` script which includes two sections like the following (one for uid and another for gid):

```
# update the uid
if [ -n "$opt_u" ]; then
  OLD_UID=$(getent passwd "${opt_u}" | cut -f3 -d:)
  NEW_UID=$(stat -c "%u" "$1")
  if [ "$OLD_UID" != "$NEW_UID" ]; then
    echo "Changing UID of $opt_u from $OLD_UID to $NEW_UID"
    usermod -u "$NEW_UID" -o "$opt_u"
    if [ -n "$opt_r" ]; then
      find / -xdev -user "$OLD_UID" -exec chown -h "$opt_u" {} \;
    fi
  fi
fi
```

The OLD_UID value is from the userid in the image, and NEW_UID is from the volume mount. When those don't match, the `usermod` command is run, followed by a recursive `chown` command to fix any files with the old uid/gid.

Note that in production, where user id's on the host can be standardized, I match the host user id to that of the image if a volume is needed, allowing me to run the entrypoint as that user instead of root. The entrypoint checks the current userid and skips the `fix-perms` script and `gosu` command if it is not root.